# Oauth 2 authentication for LinkedIn

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am developing LinkedIn app for Windows 10 in C#. In order to authenticate I have to provide callback_url in http request parameter. My question is how can I get callback_url ?? I have no website.

Comment: Linked in is being used for local authentication? or to validate a back-end account?

Comment: You have to create app on Linkedin and configure to accept requests. Then you have to have logic in your code which will creates requests to that app.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this [tutorial](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#) if you want to implement OAUTH 2.0 for Linkedin.

In general, you have to do following steps (explained in this tutorial):

1. Creating and configuring the **Linkedin application**. This application will be connected to your profile (or somebodies else who will be admin) and accept authorization requests. To do this you will use applications' endpoint.
2. You have to implement logic in your C# application which will request **Authorization Code** from the Linkedin application. That code is generated once the user is authenticated. So, when you make request user will be redirected to the page to put LinkedIn credentials.
3. Obtain **Authorization Token**. Once you obtain Access Token you have to make a request to obtain Authorization Token. This token is used to make requests for authorized resources. Basically in all resources which user cannot access if is not authorized.
4. **Make authenticated requests** with Access Token. You have to append that token in each request which user makes.

This is general flow when using Linkedin OAUTH 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My question is what should be my redirect url. I have read the tutorial many times. I am new in development. So, I need more specific information. I don't have any website.

Comment: Just tell me what I will write the redirect url ? And why ?